# Can I continue use abraded rim?

Tags: rims, rear-wheel, damage

Today my tire blew up and I had to brake by bare rim and, as a result, the rim abraded in one place from 3mm to 2mm.

Can I continue to use this rim or I need to repair it in the shop or order a new rim/entire wheel?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The rim is toast.**

Even if the sidewall is structurally sound (no cracks or anything) that’s too little remaining material to safely retain a tyre (i.e. to properly seat the tyre bead). The tyre probably also won’t sit completely round.

I don’t think this can be repaired, at least not easily or cheaply. You’ll need a new rim.

Comment: Thanks, Michael! Ordered a new wheel, because the labor cost more. Before that incident, I pumped the tire by CO2 cartridge. But did not know that this could lead the tire explosion!